# Eigenvalues of Hermitian Operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, eigenvalue, observables

In quantum mechanics, it's well-known that **observables are associated as the eigenvalue of a Hermitian operator**.

My question is, is the converse also true? i.e. **the eigenvalue of a Hermitian operator (which is real) must be an observable**.

Comment: It depends on how you define things. Yes, in "standard" QM, an observable is represented by a hermitian operator, and its eigenvalues are said to be the possible measurement outcomes. Conversely, in the absence of superslection rules, you call every hermitian operator an observable, which *in principle* you can measure. Whether or not you actually can perform an experiment coresponding to an arbitrary operator is another story.

Comment: See this post on the same topic: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/479545/

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/373357/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27038/2451 and links therein.