# Does all measured quantities by Hamiltonian operator should be real valued?

Tags: quantum-information, hamiltonian, measurements

am not familiar with QM , and i have checked web many times to know wether all measured Quantities of any arbitray system should be real since it is Hermitian ?

Comment: Yes, we use Hermitian operators because everything we measure (positions, velocities, momenta, accelerations, forces, energies, etc.) is real, not complex. So we need the eigenvalues to be real.

Comment: possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82613/84967, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27038/84967, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/75401/84967, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39602/84967

Comment: Your question is kind of convoluted and the wording is difficult to decipher.  The possible measurements of a QM system will be the eigenvalues of the Hermitian operator and these are real.  The requirement of a real valued observable forces the operators to be Hermitian.